# R, twitteR package: How can I get the twitter statuses from a specific time of the year?

Tags: r, twitter

I am quite new to R and its Twitter package.
As a student, I'm trying to get the twitter statuses of around 30 specific people during the month of October (2013, then 2012, then 2011).
I have succeeded for one of them with this code

`test.X<- userTimeline("X", n=3200, maxID=twitter-id-of-the-last-tweet-of-the-month, sinceID=twitter-id-of-the-first-tweet-of-the-month, includeRts=FALSE, retryOnRateLimit=1500)
Y <- do.call("rbind", lapply(test.X, as.data.frame))
write.table(Y,file="nameoct13.csv",sep=",",row.names=T)`

But this is going to take quite a long time, as:

1. i have to manually scroll down the timeline to get the ID of the first and last tweets of the month.
2. i have to do it 3 times for each person
3. i have to re-do this operation for 30 people.

Can anyone help with the simplification of any of these tasks ?

-

As I'm typing these lines, I reckon that a probably simpler way to do this would be to get everything from the very first tweet of the user until the last tweet of october 2013, but:

1. there is probably going to be a maximum of tweets reached (isn't it?).
2. this still leaves us (well, me, in any case) with the problem of scrolling the timelines for quite a long time... Some of the users have around 10K tweets...

Thank you to the community for its already great help.
V.A.

Comment: I realize you're looking for a pure `R` example, but if you can run Ruby scripts, I've found working with the 't' command: https://github.com/sferik/t much easier. Use that to get data and then use R for analysis & vis.

Comment: Hi @hrbrmstr , thanks for your answer. I'm just beginning with R and even a more modest beginner in Python, so I might wait a little before getting into Ruby. A friend of mine told me about a solution to my problem with "for". I am going to give it an hour's thought tomorrow. Thanks anyway for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you just can't do with `twitteR::` what you'd like to do.  `twitteR::` accesses a twitter API that only returns tweets more recent than a few weeks old.  There's no way to get historical tweets using `twitteR::` because twitter doesn't allow it.

You might have better luck scraping with `rvest`.